# Future of cs project file and nuspec file

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

We have moved our application (consisting of 20+- projects and 5 executables) to asp net core (1.1) and project.json (.xproj).

We got it all running but now we are moving certain projects as packages to our internal nuget feed. We can use project.json to create nuget packages, but we can also still use nuspec files to create packages, (although these placeholders are not auto filled anymore).

Since Microsoft announced they will drop project.json and go back to their old xml project structure, I'm wondering what will happen to nuspec support?

I have been researching this but couldn't find any information on this.

Does anyone know how the future of this project files will contain nuspec support or will nuspec files still be necessary?

Found relating resources:

- Project json documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json Says they move to msbuild
- Explains why: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/23/changes-to-project-json/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out today a preview version (preview3) is installed when you install vs2017 also you can find it here: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/preview3-download.md

This new sdk contains an `dotnet migrate` which converts project.json and xproj files back to .csproj files.

the new project files will look something like this:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard1.6</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>MyProject</AssemblyName>
    <PackageTargetFallback Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard1.6' ">$(PackageTargetFallback);dnxcore50</PackageTargetFallback>
    <GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="**\*.cs" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="**\*.resx" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="compiler\resources\**\*" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\OtherProject.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
      <Version>1.0.0-alpha-20161104-2</Version>
      <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="NETStandard.Library">
      <Version>1.6.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Common.Core">
      <Version>1.0.*</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Text.Core">
      <Version>1.0.*</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Linq.Queryable">
      <Version>4.3.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);RELEASE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

It does contain the nuget package references which makes packages.config unnecessary. It probably still needs a nuspec file like it did before.

### What i found behind

Is that based on these added Xml tags on project file, and default dotnet added msbuild prop files. dotnet will onbuild transform these tags internally back to `.nuspec` file and AssemblyVersionInfo file and then build it with those files.

Its super hacky but i guess it works. (at least thats how it used to work before the release NetStandard2.0 but i figure it still works the same)